# Re-ordering a 2d Array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array populated with cllocationcoordinate objects I want to traverse the array from the first element to the last, the issue is I want to re-order the array like so.

```
 start element = s 
 even element = e 
 odd element = o 

 order -> s o o e e o o e e o o ...
```

numerically it would look like

0 1 3 2 4 5 7 6 8 ...

I have already written a method to do this but it is inefficient and id like to see a concise method for producing the same functionality

as requested this is what im currently doing - it works but I know there must be better methods.

```
var inc = 0
       var flightPatternCounter = 0
       var hasResolvedThisIncrement = false
       for i in 0..<edgePointFlattenArrayHolder.count{
           hasResolvedThisIncrement = false
           if i == 0 {
               inc = 0
               hasResolvedThisIncrement = true
           }
           if flightPatternCounter == 0 && hasResolvedThisIncrement == false{
               inc = inc + 1
               flightPatternCounter = flightPatternCounter + 1
               hasResolvedThisIncrement = true
           }
           if flightPatternCounter == 1 && hasResolvedThisIncrement == false{
               inc = inc + 2
               flightPatternCounter = flightPatternCounter + 1
               hasResolvedThisIncrement = true
           }
           if flightPatternCounter == 2 && hasResolvedThisIncrement == false{
               inc = inc - 1
               flightPatternCounter = flightPatternCounter + 1
               hasResolvedThisIncrement = true
           }
           if flightPatternCounter == 3 && hasResolvedThisIncrement == false{
               inc = inc + 2
               flightPatternCounter = 0
               hasResolvedThisIncrement = true
           }
           if inc >= edgePointFlattenArrayHolder.count{
               inc = inc - 1
           }
           finalAutoPathPoints.append(edgePointFlattenArrayHolder[inc])
       }
```

Comment: I didn't understood the logic behind it. Is it that you want to swap object at index "% 4 == 2" with "% 4 == 3"? And if you have not enough objects to swap? Not multiple of 4?

Comment: Yes, you need to clarify your question and it would help if you showed us what you have written so far.

Comment: I have altered the post to include the code, apologies for not including it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `enumerated()` to use the index value of each element for the correct sorting

```
let sorted = elements.enumerated().sorted(by: {
    if $1.offset.isMultiple(of: 4) { return false }
    return !$0.offset.isMultiple(of: 2) && $1.offset.isMultiple(of: 2)
}).map(\.element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know its a good solution or not but you can set an order by this

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
var newArr: [Int] = []
var index = 0
var tempBool = false
while (index <= arr.count - 1)  {
    if index == 0 {
        newArr.append(arr[index])
        index += 1
    } else if index.isMultiple(of: 2) && tempBool {
        if index + 1 <= arr.count - 1 {
            newArr.append(arr[(index + 1)])
        }
        newArr.append(arr[index])
        index += 2
        tempBool = false
    } else {
        newArr.append(arr[index])
        index += 1
        tempBool = true
    }
}
print(newArr) // [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 11, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this does what you want?

```
let array = Array(0...13)

extension Array {
    func enumerateOddly(_ f: (Element) -> Void) {
        let orderedIndices =
            indices.lazy.compactMap { idx -> Index? in
                if (idx % 4) == 2 {
                    if indices.contains(idx + 1) {
                        return idx + 1
                    }
                    else { return nil }
                }
                else if (idx % 4) == 3 {
                    return idx - 1
                }
                return idx
            }
        for i in orderedIndices {
            f(self[i])
        }
    }
}

array.enumerateOddly { print($0) }
```